# Blender Cut with a Plane

Tags: blender

I have created a tube like object that has different radius sizes every 5 cm. 
I took this tube and put a cube around it. 
Cut out the form of this tube out of the cube (boolean modifier, difference).

Now I have a cube that has a hole through it with the form of the tube. 
I would like to position a plane at the center of this cube and cut it in half. 
Boolean Modifier does not work. Difference only gives me one half of the cube. 
But I want two pieces. 
Subdivide the cube faces and select the vertices and separate is great, but leaves the inner structure uncut.

Is there a simple way to cut this in half ? 
Is there an addon/script that does this ?

I already lost too much time on this and I need to solve it.

thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too easy to imagine without a screenshot so I might be totally wrong. If the boolean modifier does the job as required and provided that it's possible to choose which half to get, I would:

1. Duplicate the object in object mode (Shift-D)
2. Apply the boolean modifier to each object so that you get the two halves spread over two objects
3. Merge both objects

Maybe you can post a screenshot if I am totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this by going into wireframe mode, select everything I want and hit P. I am still not 100% happy because selecting by hand is a bit painful but at least I have what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @user413734 hav a look at [Selection Modes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting) especially `Linked`, `Circle`, `Border`, `Extend selection`

Comment: Yep a image would be a much more help. but i think as he mentioned duplicate the object in object mode (Shift-D) will be the best option in this matter